# Google developers console, API selection, Failed to load

Tags: android, google-maps

While selecting API in google developers console, failed to load error comes.

I can see that at few places this question was asked , but i couldn't get the exact answer why this issue happens, is it that Google is updating some thing so API excess is restricted.
Or is there some other reason?
I am trying to enable few API from past couple of hours but it shows failed to load. Also is there any other way to enable the API ?

Comment: What is the error? What guide are you following? Please provide a few data points for community of investigate.

Comment: When going on to the developers console, and then i select a API Manager, i can not see the option of google API and enabled API's. I have included a map activity in my application and to access MAP API i need the google to enable Map API. I tried to include the same thing from a different system and i can see all the options and able to select the API's.